# ignore certain *lines* when merging files

Tags: version-control, mercurial, diff

I have a repository with two branches, `A` and `B`.

They are meant to be the same code, but aimed at different versions of the libraries they depend on.

So `A/file1.js` might have a snippet in it like so:

```
this.actor.bar();
```

whilst `B/file1.js` might have:

```
// `bar` had its name changed to `foo` in version X.Y of library Z
this.actor.foo();
```

Then I go along into `A` say and make a whole bunch of changes that are compatible with both versions of library `Z` and want to merge them into `B`.

**Is there any way I can tell mercurial, "do a merge but ignore the lines where `*.bar()` becomes `*.foo()`"?**

Basically there are a few blocks of code that differ between branches `A` and `B` because of the version of library they depend upon, but I've written the code such that asides from those lines, the rest of the code is identical.

I just don't want to have to deal with these blocks of code every time I merge, because otherwise I'm more prone to fudge up the merge and switch some of these blocks around.

The only thing I can conceive is somehow making a different diff preset for each file that calls `diff --ignore-matching-lines [impressively_long_argument]` that is custom to each file - this seems like the wrong way to do it!

(Can I do this in git? This is a feature I'd switch versioning systems for, although I have no idea how one would implement it. Or perhaps the solution lies in finding a sophisticated `diff` tool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git and Mercurial both handle this more easily that you're imagining (and easier than, say, svn or CVS do).   That's because git and Mercurial merge *changes* not *differences*.

If you have two branches, A and B, and you've changed `bar` to `foo` in branch A when you do this:

```
hg update B
hg merge A
```

it will merge in all the *changesets* currently in A that haven't yet been merged into B.  That will include your `bar` to `foo` change and you'll have to manually exclude that specific change **but only that one time**.

The next time you do:

```
hg update B
hg merge A
```

it will again merge in all the changesets currently in A that haven't been merged to A, but since the changeset that does `bar` to `foo` has already been merged in **it doesn't matter at all** that A has `foo`s and and B has `bars`s because that difference wasn't created in the changesets now being merged, that change won't be *applied* to B and you don't have to manually reject it again.

This is one of the key advantages that a CVS with a full graph history brings.  You're not merging two snapshots, you're applying the differences that are new in branch A to branch B, so if a difference isn't new you don't have to re-reject it -- the system remembers, *"oh, I remember, you didn't want that"*.